# QStandardPaths: runtime directory '/tmp' is not owned by UID 1000, but a directory permissions 0777 owned by UID 0 GID 0 in docker container

Tags: linux, docker, permissions

This error appeared when I installed wkhtmltopdf in my container.
Here is part of my Dockerfile

```
ENV XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/tmp

RUN python3.9 -m venv /py && \
    ...
    apk add wkhtmltopdf && \
    ...
    adduser --disabled-password --no-create-home ozangue && \
    ...

ENV PATH="/scripts:/py/bin:$PATH"

USER ozangue
```

When I try to add the following lines:

```
chown -R ozangue:ozangue /tmp && \
chmod -R 755 /tmp
```

the error message changes. I get:

```
wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code -11. error:
Unknown Error
```

when I change the permissions like this:

```
chmod -R 7777 /tmp
```

I always get the precedent error message:

```
wkhtmltopdf exited with non-zero code -11. error:
    Unknown Error
```

Need help please

Answer (score 1):

Why are you messing about with permissions & ownership on `/tmp`? You should reset them to their correct settings via:

```
chown root:root /tmp
chmod 1777 /tmp
```

They are set that way for a reason.

It allows any user to create files or directories within there, and to also ensure only the owner (or root) is able to delete them.

Comment: Thank you ! I just modified but I still get the same error